Unity 3D animated player is moving away from its parent object transform
Whenever I continue moving my player around in Unity 3D, the radius between the player model transform and parent transform increases. I believe this is because of my animator because this wasn't happening before I added it. I found a tutorial telling me to add these two lines:
anim.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
anim.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;

Still this didn't help and the result was the same.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;
using Quaternion = UnityEngine.Quaternion;
using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float turnSmoothTime = .1f;

    private float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float sprintSpeed;
    private float trueSpeed;
    public Transform cam;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public float gravity;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    public Animator anim;
    public bool sprinting;
    private void Start()
    {
        trueSpeed = walkSpeed;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, .1f, 1);
        anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -1;
        }
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            trueSpeed = sprintSpeed;
            sprinting = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            trueSpeed = walkSpeed;
            sprinting = false;
        }

        anim.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        anim.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        if (direction.magnitude >= .1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = MathF.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity,
                turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir * trueSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (sprinting)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("Speed", 2);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetFloat("Speed", 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Speed", 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt((jumpHeight * 10) * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (velocity.y > -20)
        {
            velocity.y += (gravity*10) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}





please share a picture of your animation timeline. maybe you are changing your root position from animation.

this is because you have root transform properties in your animations.
1- never put animation on root. because it can mess with everything movement related.
2- if you have a transform change on your animated character, always make sure end of animation is reset to original point.
3- if you got your animations from "mixamo" then before downloading make sure you check the "in place" property.

you have solved the problem where it stays at its origin point, but now after playing the animation after a while, the animation freezes and you are just walking around with yourself midway through the animation.

@TurtleLover69 . go to your animation clip in your project windows and check "loop"       and if my answer fixed your problem, set it as the answer so others know
